# How to use this relationship in Laravel Inertia JS?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, inertiajs

My User model:

```
public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

My Role model:

```
public function count() {
    return User::where('role_id', $this->id)->count();
}
```

I want to retrieve how many users have a certain role in my Index.vue component.
When I type in Tinker:

```
$role = Role::find(1); 
$role->count();
Output: 1 -> because I have one user with a role with ID 1
```

My Vue component:

```
<li v-for="role in roles">Role name: {{ role.name }}</li>
<li>Role count: {{ role.count}}</li>
```

But this not works as planned.

My RoleController where I passed the 'roles' variable to Index.vue component:

```
public function index()
{
    return Inertia::render('Roles/Index', [
        'roles' => Role::all(),
    ]);
}
```

I want to display it like this:

---

Role name: Administrator

Role count: 1

---

Role name: Subscriber

Role count: 5

Comment: what error are you getting? what is the actual issue?

Comment: when i do {{role.count}} it's blank prints nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this:
You need to return the collection inside your controller:

```
 return Inertia::render('Roles/Index', [
        'roles' => RoleResource::collection(Role::all()),
 ]);
```

Then create RoleResource.php using the command:
`php artisan make:resource RoleResource`

And finally inside your RoleResource return these:

```
return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'count' => User::where('role_id', $this->id)->count(),
];
```

Inside your Index.vue file add "roles" as prop as object like this:
`props: {roles: Object}`

And foreach your roles:

```
<tr v-for="role in roles.data">
{{role.id}} // This will print your role id
{{role.name}} // This will print your role name
{{role.count}} // This will print how much users have that role
</tr>
```

Final result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

if count is not a column on the role table, you will need to pass that data to Vue,
unlike blade, Vue doesn't have access to model/collection methods

I always use resources to transform my data to my javascript front end.  see documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources

RoleResource

```
 return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->role()
        // .... 
    ];
```

now

```
public function index()
{
    return Inertia::render('Roles/Index', [
        'roles' => RoleResource::collection(Role::all()); //remember to import RoleResource
    ]);
}
```

Check if this helps